# Trying to combine a template with a stack, to access a text file and organize

Tags: c++, file, templates, stack

So I am trying to make a template stack that organizes a text file that has student names and GPAs into two stacks, a double and a string, and prints them out as pairs together. So far it only prints the first pair, then ends saying can't open the file, despite it opening the first time and working it closes afterward. I know it's working with the stack because it prints the last value that is in my file first, which I want it to do. I tried to use pop and push but it said it was overloaded because there were too many arguments, and I couldn't find anything with popping and pushing values that are inside a text file being organized with different doubles and chars.

```
#include <fstream> 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;
//creating 2 template class for 2 different data types
template <class T, class B>
//creating class for both
class info {
    //naming variables
    T student;
    B gpa;
public:
    //putting it in order from name to gpa
    info(T first, B second) {
        first = student;
        second = gpa;
    }

};

stack<double, string>;

int main()
{


    ifstream inFile("c:\\temp\\input.txt");

    double gpa;
    string student;
    string lempty;

    cout << "STUDENT" << "       " << "GPA" << endl;

    while (inFile >> student >> gpa);
    {
        //print student and gpa
        cout << student << " " << gpa << endl;
        getline(inFile, lempty);
    }

    if (!inFile)
    {
        cerr << "Unable to open file";
        exit(1);   // call system to stop
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This constructor makes no sense:

```
info(T first, B second) {
    first = student;
    second = gpa;
}
```

`student` and `gpa` are member variables in the class `info`.  The two assignments should be:

```
    student = first;
    gpa = second;
```

Because you want to store the arguments passed to the constructor, and `a = b` means something like "Copy the contents of b into a."